# Just installed Ubuntu but can't connect to any network whatsoever

Tags: networking

I just today got a new System 76 Lemur laptop, with Ubuntu 15.04 pre-installed. Every time I try connecting to a network, wired or wireless, it looks like it's connecting and then tells me it is disconnected.

It has yet to establish an actual connection to a network for any period of time. I tried two wireless networks, both of which are working fine on my other devices, and a wired one, also working fine.

I tried turning off the wireless card for a minute, but considering it doesn't even connect to Ethernet I didn't expect that to help (which of course it did not). I also restarted the computer, triple checked the network security settings, etc. It has to be an issue with Ubuntu or the hardware, and considering it is right out of the box I'm thinking (hoping) it's just Ubuntu. I don't want to have to send it back after waiting all this time.

I'm about ready to just reinstall, but I was hoping maybe someone here would have some idea what the deal is.

Comment: 15.04 seems to be kind of buggy. If possible try moving to 14.04 LTS or 14.10

Comment: Try running the following command `sudo iptables -F`; this flushes the ip tables.

Also please edit your question and attach the output of `dmesg` several seconds after you turn your physical wireless switch off and back to on, as well as the output of these commands:  `lshw -c network`, `rfkill list`, and `iwconfig`.

Comment: Try restarting network manager. For 15.04 you should run `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`